# How to reuse GraphQL individual query API to get the list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am trying to get the list of models.

First I have created a model query API. And now I want to get a list by providing `ids`.

I know I can use `Promise.all` on `getModelById` and do some processing to each result I get again.

But is there a way to reuse the individual model query API? Thanks

```
const ModelType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Model',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    // ...
  }
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: () => ({
    model: {
      type: ModelType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        const { id } = args;
        return getModelById(id).then(model => doSomeProcessing(model));
      }
    },

    models: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ModelType),
      args: {
        ids: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        const { ids } = args;
        // here I know I can use Promise.all on getModelById and do my doSomeProcessing again for each result I got,
        // but is there a way to reuse the model query above? Thanks
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference an existing resolver inside another resolver. The only way you can reuse the logic is by abstracting it out into a separate function that gets called by both resolvers. For example:

```
const getProcessedModelById = (id) => {
  return getModelById(id).then(model => doSomeProcessing(model))
}

// model
resolve(parentValue, args) {
  return getProcessedModelById(args.id)
}

// models
resolve(parentValue, args) {
  return Promise.all(args.ids.map(id => getProcessedModelById(args.id)))
}
```

Depending on the **kind** of processing you're doing on the model, it may be possible to do it through field resolvers on the `Model` type. Let's say your `Model` type has two fields -- `firstName` and `lastName` but your model returns a single field called `name`. Your `doSomeProcessing` is just taking that name and breaking it apart into `firstName` and `lastName`:

```
function doSomeProcessing (model) {
  const names = model.name.split(' ')
  return { firstName: names[0], lastName: names[1] }
}
```

Instead of doing that, your resolvers could just return whatever `getModelById` returns. Then you can encapsulate the "processing" logic inside each field's resolver:

```
// firstName field
resolve (parentValue) {
  return parentValue.name.split(' ')[0]
}

// lastName field
resolve (parentValue) {
  return parentValue.name.split(' ')[1]
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that the "processing" won't actually happen unless that field is requested by the client. In this very simple example, resolving the `lastName` field is not expensive, but that may not always be the case. It also very neatly encapsulates logic for fields that are derived from the underlying data layer. However, it can also end up being more expensive (imagine, for example, if the `split` call was itself expensive... now we're calling that method twice instead of once).

Comment: Yeah, that is my current way, I was just wondering if there is a GraphQL way because GraphQL to me still has too much magic. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @HongboMiao updated the answer with some additional thoughts :)